# How to Authenticate, and then use token on OAuth call in PHP

Tags: php, api, oauth

I've been looking for a simple example of how to do this in PHP:

curl -X POST "https://account.xyxyxyxyx.com/oauth2/token"  -u "xxxxxx:yyyyyyyyyy" --basic  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"  -d "scope=read:events"

Once this responds with a token, how do I use that token in the actual API query, is this just a parameter?

Any example that includes the auth call and the regular API call after in PHP would be REALLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `how do I use that token in the actual API query`...that depends on how the API in question expects you to use it. In most cases it should be sent in an `Authorization` HTTP header, but check the API documentation to be sure.

Comment: As for how to use cURL in PHP, consult https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php. Something like https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ may also give you a jump-start, since you've got an existing command-line cURL example to work with.